# Is $C=\{(x,y\in\mathbb R^2: |x|^p + |y|^p \le c\}$ a convex set for all $p \ge 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, inequality, convex-analysis

I have a question to prove the convexity of a set. Let $C=\{(x,y): |x|^p + |y|^p \le c^p \}$ where $c$ is a positive constant. I am trying to find the range of $p$ for which $C$ is convex.

I look at the function $f(x)=(c^p-x^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$. Finding $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$, I get that $f''(x)=(p-1)x^{p-2}c^p(c^p - x^p)^{\frac{1-2p}{p}}$. My guess is that for all $p \ge 2$, I can say that $C$ is convex.  Also, for $p=1$ indeed $C$ is convex. But, is there a rigorous mathematical argument to show the convexity or non-convexity of $C$?

Comment: What happens when $p=3$ and $c=1$?

Comment: It might be useful to use 3D plots to check it out. For example if you draw a graph of $x^p+y^p$ for $p=2$ you get a bowl-shaped thing which clearly is a convex function. If $p$ is an integer it also extends into the negative regions and it may or may not be convex there, for example if $p=3$ you get a saddle point at the origin. If $p<1$ then you get a different shape which is clearly not a convex function anywhere. If $p=1$ then it's a plane.

Comment: Have a look the image in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse

Comment: @SuzuHirose By the way thank you for your suggestion on my post, I got a great answer from a great person (I was inspired to study analytical number theory by him haha) @ MathsFreak Yes, your claim is true. By symmetry you only need to consider the first quadrant where $x, y \geq 0$. Then take derivative on the curve $x^p + y^p = c$ to get $\frac{dy}{dx} = -\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^{p-1}$ (note the similarity with the circle! Well since $p=2$ is a circle...), and the rest shouldn't be hard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p\geq1$ then $C$ is the ball with radius $c$ around $0$ in the $\|.\|_p$ norm. Balls under norms always form convex sets:

Suppose $\|x\|,\|y\| \leq c$. Then $$\|\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y\| \leq \lambda\|x\| + (1-\lambda)\|y\| \leq \lambda c + (1-\lambda)c = c$$

But if you look at $p<1$ the set is not convex: Simply choose the points $(c,0)$ and $(0,c)$ and you’ll see that $(c/2,c/2)$ does not lie in this set, as $(c/2)^p + (c/2)^p = 2/2^p c^p > c^p$.

Comment: If noticed you’ve added absolute values to your question, which makes a lot of the answer unnecessary, so I’ve edited it accordingly.

Comment: We could have mentioned that $\lambda\in[0,1]$ since we are interested in the segment $xy$, and therefore that $|\lambda|=\lambda$ and $|1-\lambda|=1-\lambda$ in the triangle inequality. the counterexample is nice.

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen Could have, but then this is mostly obvious, I think.

Answer (score 1):

For any $p\geq1$, the set $C$ is convex. Let $\phi(x)=x^p$ for $x\geq0$, then $\phi''(x)=p(p-1)x^{p-2}\geq0$, hence $\phi$ is a convex function: for any $\lambda\in[0,1]$ and $a,b\geq0$, we have
$$\phi(\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b)\leq\lambda \phi(a)+(1-\lambda)\phi(b),$$
i.e.
$$(\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b)^p\leq \lambda a^p+(1-\lambda)b^p.$$

If $(x,y), (u,v)\in C$, then for $\lambda\in[0,1]$, we want to prove $\lambda(x,y)+(1-\lambda)(u,v)\in C$. Indeed,
\begin{align*}
|\lambda x+(1-\lambda) u|^p+|\lambda y+(1-\lambda) v|^p&\leq (\lambda |x|+(1-\lambda) |u|)^p+(\lambda |y|+(1-\lambda) |v|)^p\\
&\leq\lambda |x|^p+(1-\lambda)|u|^p+\lambda |y|^p+(1-\lambda)|v|^p\\
&\leq \lambda c^p+(1-\lambda)c^p=c^p.
\end{align*}

For $0<p<1$, the function $\phi$ is strictly concave. If we pick two different points at the boundary of $C$ in the first quardant, then the whole segment connecting these two points (not including the endpoints of the segment) lies outside $C$.